# Sharing data between isolated microservices

Tags: web-services, heroku, database-design, web-applications, microservices

I'd like to use the microservices architectural pattern for a new system, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to share and merge data between the services when the services are isolated from each other. In particular, I'm thinking of returning consolidated data to populate a web app UI over HTTP.

For context, I'm intending to deploy each service to its own isolated environment (Heroku) where I won't be able to communicate internally between services (e.g. via `//localhost:PORT`. I plan to use RabbitMQ for inter-service communication, and Postgres for the database.

The decoupling of services makes sense for CREATE operations:

- Authenticated user with `UserId` submits 'Join group' webform on the frontend
- A new `GroupJoinRequest` including the `UserId` is added to the RabbitMQ queue
- The `Groups` service picks up the event and processes it, referencing the user's `UserId`

However, READ operations are much harder if I want to merge data across tables/schemas. Let's say I want to get details for all the users in a certain group. In a monolithic design, I'd just do a SQL `JOIN` across the Users and the Groups tables, but that loses the isolation benefits of microservices.

My options seem to be as follows:

#### Database per service, public API per service

To view all the `Users` in a `Group`, a site visitor gets a list of `UserID`s associated with a group from the Groups service, then queries the `Users` service separately to get their names.

**Pros:**

- very clear separation of concerns
- each service is entirely responsible for its own data

**Cons:**

- requires multiple HTTP requests
- a lot of postprocessing has to be done client-side
- multiple SQL queries can't be optimized

#### Database-per-service, services share data over HTTP, single public API

A public API server handles request endpoints. Application logic in the API server makes requests to each service over a HTTP channel that is only accessible to other services in the system.

**Pros:**

- good separation of concerns
- each service is responsible for an API contract but can do whatever it wants with schema and data store, so long as API responses don't change

**Cons:**

- non-performant
- HTTP seems a weird transport mechanism to be using for internal comms
- ends up exposing multiple services to the public internet (even if they're notionally locked down), so security threats grow from greater attack surface

#### Database-per-service, services share data through message broker

Given I've already got RabbitMQ running, I could just use it to queue requests for data and then to send the data itself. So for example:

- client requests all Users in a Group
- the public API service sends a `GetUsersInGroup` event with a `RequestID`
- the `Groups` service picks this up, and adds the `UserID`s to the queue
- The `Users service picks this up, and adds the User data onto the queue
- the API service listens for events with the `RequestID`, waits for the responses, merges the data into the correct format, and sends back to the client

**Pros:**

- Using existing infrastructure
- good decoupling
- inter-service requests remain internal (no public APIs)

**Cons:**

- Multiple SQL queries
- Lots of data processing at the application layer
- harder to reason about
- Seems strange to pass large quantities around data via event system
- Latency?

#### Services share a database, separated by schema, other services read from `VIEW`s

Services are isolated into database schemas. Schemas can only be written to by their respective services. Services expose a SQL `VIEW` layer on their schemas that can be queried by other services.

The `VIEW` functions as an API contract; even if the underlying schema or service application logic changes, the `VIEW` exposes the same data, so that

**Pros**:

- Presumably much more performant (single SQL query can get all relevant data)
- Foreign key management much easier
- Less infrastructure to maintain
- Easier to run reports that span multiple services

**Cons:**

- tighter coupling between services
- breaks the idea of fundamentally atomic services that don't know about each other
- adds a monolithic component (database) that may be hard to scale (in contrast to atomic services which can scale databases independently as required)
- Locks all services into using the same system of record (Postgres might not be the best database for all services)

---

I'm leaning towards the last option, but would appreciate any thoughts on other approaches.

Comment: I have no straight answer, but I just want to chime in to say that I've been thinking about this exact same issue, and your post is an excellent summary of the problem and the alternatives. My gut instinct would also be the last option, but maybe that's because I'm a DB guy foremost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To evaluate the pros and cons I think you should focus on what microservices architecture is aiming to achieve. In my opinion Microservices is architectural style aiming to build loosely couple applications. It is not designed to build high performance application so scarification of performance and data redundancy are something we are ready accept when we decided to build applications in a microservices way.

I don't think you services should share database. Tighter coupling scarify the main objective of the microservices architecture. My suggestion is to create a consolidated data service which pick up the data changes events from all the other services and update the database behind it. You might want to design the database behind the consolidated data service in a way that is optimised for query (like a data warehouse) because that's all this service will be used for. You might want to consider using a NoSQL database to support your consolidated data service.

Comment: Yeah, this seems right — keeping everything strongly decoupled, then merging into a data warehouse using a data consolidation service could be the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: its a personal choice, not that is an antipattern - 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/modernization-data-persistence/shared-database.html

https://microservices.io/patterns/data/shared-database.html